# Is any way to attempt to prove God futile? How much this quote is in line with Hindu philosophies?

Tags: philosophy, brahman

This is a saying of Nisargadatta Maharaj, a self realized master of nAth Sampradaye. His teachings are non dualistic in nature. 
[image]
A similar question I have [posted](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47104/can-god-not-be-proved-by-any-means-presuming-if-it-exists-it-must-be-immanent) here as well. My question is which Indian philosophies are consistent with this thought?

---

I guess Pratyabhijna philosophy of Kashmiri Shaivism is consistent with this thought but not have reference of this so far.

Comment: consistent with advaita.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thank. Can you write answer?